# Is it possible to remove Markers in Android Google Maps API v.2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to develop an android application using Google Maps API v.2 is it possible to remove the default markers placed by Google such as bus markers.

Sorry for the basic question but this is my first time developing an android application.

Comment: yes it possible if you try searching you might have got answer till now

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to remove the default markers placed by Google such as bus markers.

There are no default markers. Whatever "markers" you are seeing are part of the map tiles, and cannot be removed.

Answer (score -1):

What is your aim ? You dont use them, you dont need them to remove!!! In maps you have to show a POI like as a marker. Otherwise it does not make a sense.

You can replace the icon with a transparent drawable... :)