# Remove google places icons

Tags: android, android-maps

How can i remove google places marks? As shown below, that are markers that i didn't placed on the map (marked in blue). BTW, it is possible to use google place's markers instead of my own custom marker (marked in red).

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: please submit your code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can i remove google places marks?

If you have added your custom marker, yes you can delete it. But if you are asking about google map default tiles(bus,restaurent etc), no you can't delete those. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295687/is-it-possible-to-remove-markers-in-android-google-maps-api-v-2?rq=1)

**Update after September 2016**

yes now you can remove those icons, see [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4841#c11) issue.

please check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#september_21_2016

you need to set map style off `GoogleMap`

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));
```

your `style_json` will look like this

```
[
    {
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

[Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos) is the full demo which explains everything

Comment: You can generate your style.json here: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: how to remove all markers of any type?