# How to remove landmarks from google map with google map angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the [google map angular component](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component#marker-input-properties) and it's working pretty good!

But now I want to remove some of the landmarks from the map to reduce its congestion, to be able to show my markers a little more clearly.

I've found these resources below but can't figure out how to apply it to the <google-map> node package I'm using.

1. [Site to create json for hiding landmarks and other features on map](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)
2. [shows how to hide map features from google map dev site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/hiding-features#raw-resource)
3. [SO link that describes same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354888/remove-google-places-icons)

I see in this [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/hiding-features#raw-resource) it shows applying styles to 'googlemap' with 'setMapStyle()' but this isn't a method in the angular package

Here below is my component (not all code) where I'm using google maps but it shows how I'm using the all code for the map

```js
import {
  MapInfoWindow,
  MapMarker,
  GoogleMap
} from '@angular/google-maps';

export class YogabandEventsComponent implements OnInit {
  colContentRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, {
    static: false
  }) googleMap: GoogleMap;
  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, {
    static: false
  }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;

  zoom = 12;
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 10,
    streetViewControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false
  };

  markers: Marker[];
  infoContent = '';

  constructor(...) { ...
  }

  openInfo(marker: MapMarker, content) {
    this.infoContent = content;
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }

  showMarkers() {
    this.markers = [];
    for (const ybEvent of this.yogabandEvents) {
      const marker = new Marker();
      marker.info = ybEvent.name;
      marker.title = ybEvent.name;
      marker.position = {
        lat: ybEvent.latitude,
        lng: ybEvent.longitude
      };
      marker.label = {
        color: '#17a2b8',
        text: ybEvent.yogaType,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '16px'
      };
      marker.options = {
        icon: {
          // scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
          url: 'assets/images/marker.svg',
          labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(18, 50)
        }
      };
      this.markers.push(marker);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="col flex-fill h-100 px-0 right-col">
  <google-map [options]="options" [zoom]="zoom" [center]="center" class="h-100" height="100%" width="100%">
    <map-marker #markerElem *ngFor="let marker of markers" [position]="marker.position" [label]="marker.label" [title]="marker.title" [options]="marker.options" (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem, marker.info)">
    </map-marker>
    <map-info-window>{{ infoContent }}</map-info-window>
  </google-map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the [styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapTypeStyle) property of the [MapOptions interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions).
Like this:

```
options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scrollwheel: true,
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 10,
    streetViewControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    styles: [...]
  };
```

It could gets a bit annoying styling it detailed. You can generate a set of styles from this [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) (it also have a **Landmarks** slide to remove them gradually, then just export the styles array).

Comment: Hi Thanks! That seemed to work. I created some styles from the wizard and then pasted it into the styles property in the MapOptions.

Comment: Great! Please, help me up-voting and marking the answer as correct if that solved your issue. And come back if you need anything else ;) I know it could be a pain sometimes working with maps. Haha

Comment: actually I do have another question but was going to post in a new thread. I'd like to set the background-color of the marker label. I've set the position with 'labelOrigin' and looking in dev tools at the tags I can't see anything that I can use to color the background.

Comment: Actually I think to keep things organized (and IDK if rules say something about it), it could be better to set a thread since it's not what the title says. So maybe it's better to create to post the a new question or update this to cover both items.

Comment: I posted a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845022/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-google-map-marker-label